# Dual-boot resize

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04

Good afternoon, I've a dual-boot installed (windows not working and Ubuntu), I want to increase the size of Ubuntu partition, can someone tell me how I could do?

Comment: The easiest way is to backup data and re install.  Working on partitions can sometimes damage data so back up first.  Will need ubuntu installer USB and use gparted from that, if not re installing. have all partitions unmounted and read up on resizing partitions.  Without knowing how your partitions are, think this is all information I can give.

Comment: You almost always want to resize Windows NTFS partition from within Windows to prevent damage. If often works from gparted, but if issues users blame Linux when really Windows issue. Safest to always use Windows tools for Windows & Linux tools for Linux. Post this: `sudo parted -l`